# How can microservice can talk to other microservice in JHipster

Tags: jhipster, microservices

I am planning to create a microservice aplication with a dedicated service for dealing with data (mostly a Mongodb based service). I am wondering if there is a way using which my other microservices will be able to communicate with this service to make use of the shared data. Is it possible with JHipster API Gateway ?
If not how can I achieve this. I dont want to keep multiple copies of the same data within each microservice.

Comment: Dependencies between microservices should be avoided as much as possible, it just makes your overall solution slower and weaker, it could be a sign that your domain boundaries are wrong (see DDD). Your question lacks details but the gateway passes a JWT token to a service which can forward it to another service

Comment: Don't do a dedicated data storage. Each MS should have its own persistence.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou, what if the request is initiated by a batch call or directly from a service itself not from the gateway?

Comment: I don't see any difference. Maybe you should open your own question with more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can register your microservices to the same registry and then they can call each other.

**UPDATE** :  Here is how I made it work.
In the microservice consuming the data one, use RestTemplate with the current user's jwt-token in the Authorization-header for the API calls :

```
@Component
public class AuthenticateClientHttpRequestInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest httpRequest, byte[] bytes, ClientHttpRequestExecution clientHttpRequestExecution) throws IOException {
        String token = SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserJWT();
        httpRequest.getHeaders().add("Authorization","Bearer "+token);
        return clientHttpRequestExecution.execute( httpRequest, bytes );
    }
}
```

My custom restTemplate using ClientHttpRequestInterceptor for adding token in header.

```
@Configuration
public class CustomBean {
    @Autowired
    AuthenticateClientHttpRequestInterceptor interceptor;
    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.setInterceptors(Collections.singletonList(interceptor));
        return restTemplate;
    }
}
```

And in the resource controller where your are making the call for data:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class DataResource {    
    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

            @PostMapping("/hello")
            @Timed
            public ResponseEntity<Hello> createHello(@RequestBody Hello Hello) throws URISyntaxException {
                
    //The name your data micro service registrated in the Jhipster Registry
                String dataServiceName = "data_micro_service";
            
                URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("//" + dataServiceName + "/api/datas")
                    .build()
                    .toUri();
            
                //call the data microservice apis
                List<Data> result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, Data[].class);
            
            
            return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/hellos/" + result.getId()))
                    .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert(ENTITY_NAME, result.getId().toString()))
                    .body(result);
        
        }

}
```

Comment: Lifesaver! I've been trying to figure this out for a couple of weeks now...

Answer (score 7):

You can also use Feign clients with JHipster.

Annotate your `SpringBootApplication` with `@EnableFeignClients`

```
...
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.EnableFeignClients;
...
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties({LiquibaseProperties.class, ApplicationProperties.class})
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableFeignClients
public class MyApp {
    ...
}
```

Create a Feign client in your microservice

```
...
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
...
@FeignClient("another-service")
public interface AnotherClient {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/api/another")
    List<AnotherDTO> getAll();
}
```

Inject the Feign client with `@Autowired` and call it. It should be ready to use.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MyResource {
    ...
    @Autowired
    private AnotherClient anotherClient;
    ...
    @GetMapping("/another")
    @Timed
    public List<AnotherDTO> getAll() {
        log.debug("REST request to get all");
        return anotherClient.getAll();
    }
}
```

For us, it worked without implementing a `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` and setting a JWT token.

Answer (score 0):

Typically microservices talk to each other. Thats the whole point. With Eureka discovery in place you simply call the microservice by name instead of the FQDN which we normally would use without microservice.

For e.g. your `book-service` will call the `author-service` like this
`http://author-service/authors`

full example here https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/20/microservice-registration-and-discovery-with-spring-cloud-and-netflix-s-eureka

Please don't forget that JHipster is an opinionated framework based off of Spring Cloud so you can find most of this stuff by searching Spring docs.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below solution :
Microservice A (i.e UAA-SERVICE), and Microservice B
Microservice B want to connect microservice A and call services with Feign client.

**1)This code for Microservice B**
Client proxy :- @AuthorizedFeignClient(name = "UAA-SERVICE")

```
@AuthorizedFeignClient(name = "UAA-SERVICE")
```

public interface UaaServiceClient {

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "api/users")
public List<UserDTO> getUserList();

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, path = "api/user-info")
public String updateUserInfo(@RequestBody UserDTO userDTO);
```

}

UAA-SERVICE : find this name with running Application Instances with registry.

**2) In Microservice B (application.yml)**
Increase feign client connection Time Out:
feign:
client:
config:
default:
connectTimeout: 10000
readTimeout: 50000

Increase hystrix Thread time out:-

hystrix:
command:
default:
execution:
isolation:
thread:
timeoutInMilliseconds: 60000
shareSecurityContext: true

**3) add @EnableFeignClients in main @SpringBootApplication class.**
This solution is working fine for me.